# react native : what is the way to change the class component to a function component and hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

what is the way to change the class component to a function component ?
in my example i have class component and i try to change it to function component and hooks .
how should i do it ?
The change is a bit confusing and unclear so I was not able to make it and I was happy to see how such a change is made

```
export default class AzureLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      azureLoginObject: {},
      loginSuccess: false,
      loading: true,
    };
    this.azureInstance = new AzureInstance(credentials);
    this._onLoginSuccess = this._onLoginSuccess.bind(this);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const firstTime = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-TOKEN');
    if (firstTime != null) {
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('דגימות איכות מים'));
    } else {
      this.setState({ loginSuccess: firstTime != null, loading: false });
    }
  }

  _onLoginSuccess() {
    this.azureInstance
      .getUserInfo()
      .then(async (result) => {
        console.log(result);
        //HERE EXAMPLE FOR STORE SOME VARIABLE INTO MY REDUX STORE
        store.dispatch(userPrincipalName(result.userPrincipalName));
        store.dispatch(givenName(result.mobilePhone));
        ///THIS IS AZURE TOKEN
        // console.log('AZURE-TOKEN', JSON.stringify(this.azureInstance.token));

        ///SAVE AZURE-TOKEN INTO AsyncStorage
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'AZURE-TOKEN',
          JSON.stringify(this.azureInstance.token)
        );
        ///SAVE AZURE-USERNAME INTO AsyncStorage
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'AZURE-USERNAME',
          result.userPrincipalName.split('@')[0]
        );

        this.setState({
          loginSuccess: true,
          azureLoginObject: result,
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(
          StackActions.replace('דגימות איכות מים')
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.loading)
      return (
        <AzureLoginView
          azureInstance={this.azureInstance}
          loadingMessage="Requesting access token"
          onSuccess={this._onLoginSuccess}
        />
      );
    return <ActivityIndicator />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check this tutorial you might find it helpful
https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/blog/convert-react-class-to-function-component

Comment: i try it but also got some errors , can u help me convert it ?

Comment: What have you tried (share attempt here in question) and what are the errors (again, update and share in question)?

Comment: i make salad in my code while try change it to function component so i cant share it coz everything not well done there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps.

1. Convert state to `useState` react hooks. You can also use a function initializer to save a new AzureInstance in state. You *could* also use a ref.
2. Convert `componentDidMount` to `useEffect` with empty dependency array. Create inner async function and invoke.
3. Convert all references of `this` to the new instanceless reference (mostly just remove `this` from everything).
4. Destructure passed props in the function signature

The following should get you close.

Code:

```
const AzureLogin = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [azureInstance] = useState(() => new AzureInstance(credentials));
  const [azureLoginObject, setAzureLoginObject] = useState({});
  const [loginSuccess, setLoginSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const firstTime = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-TOKEN');

      if (firstTime) {
        navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('דגימות איכות מים'));
      } else {
        setLoginSuccess(firsTime !== null);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    loadData();
  }, []);

  const _onLoginSuccess = () => {
    azureInstance
      .getUserInfo()
      .then(async (result) => {
        console.log(result);
        //HERE EXAMPLE FOR STORE SOME VARIABLE INTO MY REDUX STORE
        store.dispatch(userPrincipalName(result.userPrincipalName));
        store.dispatch(givenName(result.mobilePhone));
        ///THIS IS AZURE TOKEN
        // console.log('AZURE-TOKEN', JSON.stringify(azureInstance.token));

        ///SAVE AZURE-TOKEN INTO AsyncStorage
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'AZURE-TOKEN',
          JSON.stringify(azureInstance.token)
        );
        ///SAVE AZURE-USERNAME INTO AsyncStorage
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          'AZURE-USERNAME',
          result.userPrincipalName.split('@')[0]
        );

        setLoginSuccess(true);
        setAzureLoginObject(result);

        navigation.dispatch(
          StackActions.replace('דגימות איכות מים')
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  return loading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
    <AzureLoginView
      azureInstance={azureInstance}
      loadingMessage="Requesting access token"
      onSuccess={_onLoginSuccess}
    />
  );
}
```